# How to fix Hive Error after collect_list, collect_set or group_concat?

Tags: hive

Suppose my hive table contains these values:

```
------------+------------------------+
| col1  |       col2        |
+------------+------------------------+
| philippe   | 24-DEC-18 05.16.32 PM  |
| hie        | 24-DEC-18 05.18.26 PM  |
| philippe   | 26-DEC-18 05.16.32 PM  |
| hie        | 26-DEC-18 05.18.26 PM  |
+------------+------------------------+
```

I'm using `hive 2.3.4`. I get this error after collect_list/collect_set or group_concat query.

```
select col1, collect_set(col2) from table_name group by col1;
```

> Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
>               at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
>               at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257)
>               at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
>               at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348)
>               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>               at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>               at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1893)
>               at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362)
>               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) (state=08S01,code=2)

Comment: Open job tracker, find failed container and get logs. Without them it is not possible to understand what actually caused the error.

Comment: seems like authentication issue, are you able to run `select * from table_name`

Comment: Where can I find jobTracker logs? I'm using beeline to execute hive queries.

Comment: Yes. I'm able to run select * from table_name.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by killing hiveserver process and running it again. Could anyone explain why that does happen?